# Tag Challenge! June 24 to July 7: Self-Publishing, Planning, Constructed-Language - RESULTS

Tags: discussion, tags, site-promotion, contest

Welcome to stage 2 of our tag challenge! [Stage 1 was very successful](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2015/33442) so we [decided to keep going](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2016/33442), with a few slight changes.

The tags:

- [self-publishing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-publishing) started at 257 questions
- [planning](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning) started at 189 questions
- [constructed-language](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constructed-language) started at 24 questions

---

## TAGS OF THE FORTNIGHT PROMO

### Results:

This tag challenge was extremely quiet. Unfortunately we only gained a collective 2 questions on the features tags. [planning](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning) added nothing, while [self-publishing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-publishing) and [constructed-language](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constructed-language) added one each.

Nonetheless, we did have a winner. **celtschk** asked an excellent question on con-langs and gets awarded a big bag of bragging rights. Use them wisely.

### Rules:

- The contest runs for two weeks, Monday 12:01am to Sunday midnight. The day ends when StackExchange says it does.
- Post a new question using one or more of the tags.
- Update the answer to this post with your name, tag(s), and a link to the question.
- You get one point for every question that, at the end of the challenge, is open, has one or more votes, and is correctly tagged.
- Re-tagging old questions on these tags is encouraged but keep it at a reasonable rate. We don't want to flood the homepage.

### Prizes:

- One beautiful sack of bragging rights!
- Two sacks if you use multiple tags in the same question.
- A third if you manage to tie a question in to the latest [writing exercise](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-exercise).

---

**Notes:**

- Can we use questions we've already posted that are within this challenge's boundaries?  Yes.
- The goal of this challenge is:

  - Increase overall question rates toward 10 questions per day.
  - Get us to the Generalist badge by having 40 tags with over 200 questions.
  - Promote tags that may otherwise be lost or forgotten.
- Each fortnight we'll have thee tags to choose from; the tags are deliberately different from each other.

  - One tag will be a high popularity tag to increase participation in the challenge.
  - One tag will start the challenge between 100 and 200 questions to move us toward generalist.
  - One tag will be freely chosen by the challenge poster. Though tags from the [new tab](https://writing.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new) are encouraged.

Answer (score 2):

## Entries

Add entries to this list in the following format:

Username, tag, link to question

One entry per question, not one entry per tag.

---

- celtschk, [constructed-language](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constructed-language), [Does it make sense to (partially) create a conlang that you don't intend to actually use in the story?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/46332/does-it-make-sense-to-partially-create-a-conlang-that-you-dont-intend-to-actu)